# Linux Distribution for bioinformatics?

Tags: distribution-choice, distributions, bioinformatics

I need a linux distro which is designed for bioinformatics including some bioinformatics tool, a sample database, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty much any distro will do if you install the right packages. There is a list of most-commonly-used distributions [here](http://www.bioinformatics.org/wiki/Software#Popular_Linux_OS_distributions_for_bioinformatics), also you can follow the [Ubuntu Science - Biology guide.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuScience/Biology)

Comment: OpenDiscovery looks promising. It seems to be based on RedHat - I wonder - why is there nothing based on Scientific Linux?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [SciTech Fedora Spin](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/SIGs/SciTech) and the [Scientific KDE Fedora Spin](http://spins.fedoraproject.org/scientific-kde/).